# An error occurs when using openpyxl: "ValueError: Invalid character : found in sheet title"

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, python-3.10

I was trying to create a workbook and change its title to time for now:

```
class Roll_call_list():
    __file_name = ''
    def __init__(self):
        self.__file_name = input("Input your file name:")+'.xlsx'
        if os.path.isfile(self.__file_name):
            self.load()
        else:
            self.new_workbook()
        self.save_file()
    def new_workbook(self):
        self.workbook = Workbook()
        self.worksheet = self.workbook.active
        self.paint_sheet()
    def load(self):
        self.workbook = load_workbook(self.__file_name)
        self.worksheet = self.workbook.create_sheet()
        self.paint_sheet()
    def paint_sheet(self):
        local_time = time.localtime(time.time())
        self.worksheet.title = f'{local_time.tm_hour}:{local_time.tm_min}'
```

But it raise a value error like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\code\python\selenium\MeetRollCaller\main.py", line 176, in <module>
    roll_call_list = Roll_call_list()
  File "d:\code\python\selenium\MeetRollCaller\main.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.new_workbook()
  File "d:\code\python\selenium\MeetRollCaller\main.py", line 68, in new_workbook
    self.paint_sheet()
  File "d:\code\python\selenium\MeetRollCaller\main.py", line 75, in paint_sheet
    self.worksheet.title = f'{local_time.tm_hour}:{local_time.tm_min}'
  File "C:\Users\ZIV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\child.py", line 93, in title
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid character : found in sheet title
```

It seems like I have a same title as a sheet in the workbook, but this is a brand new work book without any   sheet. I have no idea why it occurs.

Can someone help me fix the error and tell me why?

Comment: You're setting the title of the sheet: `self.worksheet.title`, not the workbook, which would be `self.title`

Comment: error didn't occur, but the title isn't set

Comment: The exception is self-explanatory: colons may not be used in sheetnames.